# android studio のstyle.xmlで設定してもアクションバーを消せない。

Tags: android, java, android-studio

android studio のstyle.xmlで
parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
を設定しても、アクションバーが消えません。
どのような原因が考えられますでしょうか。
テストはnexus7の実機を使っています。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。

Comment: 質問タイトルを具体化しました。[ask]もご一読ください。

Comment: 編集したstyle.xmlのフォルダと、Nexus 7のOSバージョンを教えてください

Answer (score 2):

java側で

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

とすれば非表示になります。